# Built in function to compute random numbers from a list

Tags: random, julia

In Julia 0.6, is there a way to calculate elements from a Poisson distribution taken from a predefined array? For example,

```
julia> rand([1,2,3])
```

computes a random element from `[1,2,3]`. Does exist something like:

```
julia> poisson([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Perhaps, what you mean is to sample a Poisson (with mean 1.0) number of elements from `[1,2,3]`. In this case, `sample([1,2,3],rand(Poisson(1.0)),replace=false)` would do it.

Comment: @DanGetz you should probably point out which module the `sample` function is in

Comment: `sample` is in StatsBase package, but it is also re-exported by Distributions package, so `using Distributions` (needed for Poisson) is enough.

Answer (score 3):

In Julia, you have a package by the name `Distributions.jl` which gives the functionality to compute various different distributions.

For Poissons, you may use this,

```
julia> Pkg.add("Distributions")
julia> using Distributions

julia> x = Poisson(2.1)
Distributions.Poisson{Float64}(λ=2.1)

julia> rand(x, 5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
2
0
3
5
1

julia> @which(rand(x,10))
rand(d::Distributions.Distribution{Distributions.Univariate,S} where S<:Distributions.ValueSupport, n::Int64)
```